# How to access Azure DevOps Stage name in Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to write some Powershell logic that looks at the release stage name and implements some code based on the environment being released to.

For instance, if my stage is named "DEV", I'm going to do xyz, or if my stage is "QA" I'm going to do abc...

I've tried something like this:

```
 $s = $(Release.EnvironmentName)

 $s = $(System.StageDisplayName)

 if ($s -like "DEV") 
 {
   // execute some code
 }
```

but every time, it blows up because it says "DEV" is not a recognized command outlet, etc. I've tried injecting the predefined variables in the if block, but it also blows up.

Any help on syntax?

```
DEV : The term 'DEV' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
2022-02-14T19:50:59.5173313Z spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
2022-02-14T19:50:59.5174118Z At D:\_agent1\_work\_temp\....ps1:37 char:21
2022-02-14T19:50:59.5174759Z +                 if (DEV -like DEV)
2022-02-14T19:50:59.5175946Z +                     ~~~
2022-02-14T19:50:59.5176689Z     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (DEV:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
2022-02-14T19:50:59.5177416Z     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my Powershell scripts wasn't work without quotes around azure devops variables, try something like this:

```
$branchSource = "$(Build.SourceBranch)"
$branchSourcePath = $branchSource -replace "refs/heads/", ""

switch -Wildcard ( $branchSourcePath )
{
    "rc" {}
    "develop" {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're executing that inside Azure DevOps inline PowerShell, then you need to wrap system variables in single quotes as shown below.

```
$Environment = '$(Release.EnvironmentName)'
```

When not wrapped in quotes ADO is trying to execute it as a command.

```
# Assuming Release.EnvironmentName = DEV
Write-Host $(hostname) # this will pass, because it's a real command
Write-Host $(Release.EnvironmentName) # this will fail command DEV does not exist
Write-Host '$(Release.EnvironmentName)' # Instead this will work in ADO note the single quotes
```